# How to set a variable at [formControl] in Angular 5?

Tags: javascript, angular-material, angular5, input-field, angularjs-ng-form

I have my interface like this

```
export interface IFilterParams {
    columnTitle: string;
    key: string;
    mode: FILTER_MODE;
    compareMethod: COMPARE_METHOD;
    keyToCheck?: string;
    sliderKeys?: string[];
    startingValue?: number;
    placeHolder?: string;
    cssClass?: string;
    formControl?: string;
}
```

which I use to create html (filter form) like below

```
<div [ngClass]="(filter.cssClass || 'col-md-4') + 'mt-2 pt-1'">
                  <div class="filter-key-label">
                      {{filter.columnTitle}}
                  </div>
                  <div class="filter-form-control d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-left">
                    <mat-form-field class="full-width">
                      <input type="text" matInput [formControl]="filter.formControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto" (change)="handleEmptyInput($event, filter.key)">
                        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
                          <mat-option *ngFor="let option of getOptionsTypeAhead(filter.key, filter.formControl) | async" [value]="option" (onSelectionChange)="typeaheadChange($event, filter.key)">
                            {{ option }}
                          </mat-option>
                        </mat-autocomplete>
                      </mat-form-field>
                  </div>
```

Now as you can see, I am trying to bring in values from the filter variable (look at how I am passing `filter.key`)

The thing is, I am unable to pass a variable value to `[formControl]` as it's throwing me

> TypeError: Cannot create property 'validator' on string 'country' at setUpControl

for

```
  {
    key: 'country',
    mode: FILTER_MODE.AUTOCOMPLETE,
    columnTitle: 'Country',
    compareMethod: COMPARE_METHOD.ONE_TO_ONE,
    formControl: 'countryForm',
    cssClass: ''
  },
```

What am I doing wrong here? I want to use the same html to generate different forms with different form control names.

### Update

This didn't work even after adding the direct string based variable in my component.ts file like this

```
countryForm: FormControl = new FormControl();
```

Comment: you back end ?? i.e. ts file

Comment: The update part of my question is the only ts part u would need for now

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a string object to the formControl property with `[formControl]="filter.formControl"`:

```
countryForm: FormControl = new FormControl();

filter = {
    ...
    formControl: 'countryForm',
}
```

But you need to pass a FormControl object:

```
countryForm: FormControl = new FormControl();

filter = {
    ...
    formControl: this.countryForm,
}
```